# Random number stays the same

Tags: c, random

So I' ve written this piece of code **inside** a function, that its purpose is to generate a number in the [1-3] range so I can use it in a swich/case statement. The first time the program uses the function I get a random number in [1-3]. When the program uses the function again, it only gives the same number as the first.

```
srand((int)time(NULL));
    double a;
    int num;

    a = (double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1);
    a = a * 3 + 1;
    num = (int)a;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us instead of describing parts of the code.

Comment: *"its purpose is to generate a number in the [1-3] range so I can use it in a swich/case statement"* So, why are you not using a simple `int num = rand() % 3 + 1;` (once you have moved away the `srand` call)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pseudo-random number generator will produce the same stream of numbers if seeded with the same seed. Every time `srand` is called the stream will restart. You're using `time` which is in seconds. If your function calls are within the same second, they'll get the same stream.

The first part of the solution is to only call `srand` once at the start of the program. But this is only a partial solution. `time` alone is a poor seed, and unfortunately, it's in all the tutorials. If the program is run in the same second it will get the same random numbers.

A better seed, on Unix, is to read from `/dev/random`.

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("/dev/random", "r");
    if( fp == NULL ) {
        perror("Could not open /dev/random");
    }

    unsigned int seed;
    fread(&seed, sizeof(seed), 1, fp);
    srand(seed);

    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        printf("%d\n", rand());
    }
}
```

`rand` is a very poor random number generator. If you need random numbers for security purposes, ones that nobody will be able to guess, use a proper cryptography library.

Comment: Calling srand at the start of the program solved it, thanks!